# Is there a way to make handling of Arrays in SML more pleasant?

Tags: sml

When implementing algorithms in SML I often wonder if there is a simple way to make code that makes heavy use of arrays more readable. For instance if I define a SML function to swap 2 elements in an array, the code is ...

```
local open Array in 
  fun exch (a, i, j) = 
    let
      val tmp = sub (a, i)
      val _ = update (a, i, sub (a, j))
      val _ = update (a, j, tmp)
    in () end
end
```

What I would like to have is a more readable, cleaner Version like in this Scala-snippet ...

```
def exch[T](a: Array[T], i: Int, j: Int) {
  val tmp = a(i)
  a(i) = a(j)
  a(j) = tmp
}
```

For something as simple as swapping 2 elements in an array, the SML version is okay. But as soon as the algorithms get more complex the code becomes more and more incomprehensible and does obfuscate the underlying algorithm.

A slightly more complex example would be this stack (implemented as resizable array) ...

```
structure ArrayStack = struct
  type 'a stack = ('a option array * (int ref)) ref
  exception Empty
  fun mkStack () = ref (Array.array (1, NONE), ref 0)
  fun isEmpty (ref (_, ref 0)) = true
    | isEmpty _ = false
  fun resize (array as ref (xs, n), capacity) =
      let 
        val length = Array.length xs
      in
        array := (Array.tabulate (
                     capacity,
                     fn i => if i < length then Array.sub (xs, i) else NONE
                   ), n)
      end
  fun push (array as ref (xs, n : int ref), x) = 
    if Array.length xs = !n then (
      resize (array, !n*2)
    ; push (array, x)) 
    else (
      Array.update (xs, !n, SOME x)
    ; n := !n+1)
  fun pop (ref (xs, ref 0)) = raise Empty
    | pop (array as ref (xs, n : int ref)) =  let
      val _ = (n := !n-1)
      val x = Array.sub (xs, !n)
      val _ = Array.update (xs, !n, NONE)
      val q = (Array.length xs) div 4
      val _ = if !n > 0 andalso !n = q then resize (array, q) else ()
    in 
      valOf x
    end
end
```

By comparison with the java implementation at http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/ResizingArrayStack.java.html the implementation (especially of push/pop) becomes hard to read.

How can I make such code more readable?

Comment: Because the code is working, this is probably better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true, arrays are rather awkward to use in SML. To some degree this is intentional, to discourage their use -- because most of the time, they are not the best choice of data structure. Your stack is a good example, since it is much better implemented as a list:

```
structure ListStack =
struct
  type 'a stack = 'a list ref

  fun stack () = ref nil
  fun isEmpty s = List.null (!s)
  fun push (s, x) = s := x::(!s)
  fun pop s =
      case !s of
        nil => raise Empty
      | x::xs => (s := xs; x)
end
```

(In fact, you wouldn't even normally do that, and avoid a stateful data structure like this altogether, using plain lists instead.)

If your concern is the allocation involved with lists, then note that (a) it is not doing more allocations than the array version (one :: instead of one SOME per push), and (b) allocations are very cheap in a language like SML.

But since your question is about using arrays, here is a slightly more idiomatic implementation of your array stack:

```
structure ArrayStack =
struct
  open Array infix sub

  datatype 'a stack = Stack of {data : 'a option array ref, size : int ref}

  fun stack () = Stack {data = ref (array (1, NONE)), size = ref 0}

  fun isEmpty (Stack {size, ...}) = !size = 0

  fun resize (data, len') =
      let val data' = array (len', NONE) in
        copy {src = !data, dst = data', di = 0};
        data := data'
      end

  fun push (Stack {data, size}, x) =
      let val size' = !size + 1 in
        if size' > length (!data) then resize (data, !size * 2) else ();
        update (!data, !size, SOME x);
        size := size'
      end

  fun pop (Stack {data, size}) =
      if !size = 0 then raise Empty else
      let
        val _ = size := !size - 1
        val x = !data sub (!size)
        val q = length (!data) div 4
      in
        update (!data, !size, NONE);
        if q > 0 andalso !size = q then resize (data, q) else ();
        valOf x
      end
end
```

In particular, I made `sub` infix, which allows you to write `arr sub i`. I did this just for demonstration, in this example it's not really worth it, with only one such usage.

Comment: One more question regarding the list vs. array implementation issue ... Isn't the array implementation preferable in terms of a more compact memory representation which might lead to storing the data in the CPU cache? Or do today ML compilers already take care of this, so that there is no disadvantage in using lists?

Comment: @gruenewa, no, in fact, it's probably the opposite. Each entry is an indirection through SOME, which is freshly allocated each time. If you use such a stack for a while, that will result in an array in the old generation with lots of inter-generational pointers to SOME objects in the young generation (which in turn might point to a value in the old generation again). That is the least ideal situation. A purely functional solution is potentially the cheapest, since it avoids old-to-young pointers and the substantial cost for going through write barriers altogether.

Comment: There is a minor bug in the ArrayStack implementation. The Array.copy function does raise an exception in case Stack.pop () shrinks the array, since the new array is smaller.

Comment: You are right about the performance. I put together a simple benchmark which did loop 1000 times pushing 1000.000 items and then poping 1000.000 items. The result was that ListStack is roughly 2x as fast as the ArrayStack. Compiler was MLton.

Comment: @gruenewa, ah, yes, sorry about the bug. Re performance: Have you also compared against a purely functional list stack, i.e., without the ref? I assume that will be even faster.

Comment: You could also try a version of ArrayStack where the constructor requires an argument of type 'a, used to pre-fill the array. Then you can avoid the option type, which might make it perform closer to, or even better than, the ListStack.

Comment: The results are: stateful ListStack (9.3s); purely functional List (10.2s); ArrayStack with Fillvalue (16.8s); ArrayStack with option (26.3s). The numbers are not exact and meant to just give a rough impression. I would like to note that the purely functional ListStack used a different main()-function (making use of recursion), so that it might be an apple vs. orange comparision.